# How to get a XAML Button Tapped event to fire for all taps?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a couple buttons that act as +/- stepper controls for a quantity. The default behavior of Windows is to absorb a tap if it is considered a double tap and will not fire a second tapped event:

> If a user interaction also fires DoubleTapped, Tapped will fire first to represent the first tap, but the second tap won't fire an additional Tapped.

But this provides a very poor user experience for a stepper button. The user should be able to tap it as quickly as they want and it should increment the counter each time, not every other tap as it is currently doing.

The strange thing is I can't find how to do this anywhere. At first I thought I had it with the `IsDoubleTapEnabled` property, but this sadly does buck all. Exact same behavior whether it's turned on or off.

Comment: An easy fix would be to set the button.MouseDoubleClick += increment(); or whatever class you are using on for your click event. That way they both trigger the same method. Make sure you do that only once in the Initialize section or you will end up having your increment method activate multiple times for each doubleclick event.

Comment: I thought of that, but it feels super hacky and I wanted to see if there was actually a "correct" way to do it.

Comment: The pain is compounded by the fact that the double tap handler has a different signature so you can't even share the same method.

Comment: You can use button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event instead. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way - use a *built-in* `RepeatButton` instead. It even handles **pressed state** automatically so you can press and hold on it to change the values continuously.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this would be calling the single tapped event in the double tap handler. It can only be done if you don't want the `arguments` passed in through the event.

But it's always nice to have the data even though it's not required at the moment, you would never know what and when do you want to scale to so you could create a simple `BridgeClass` as I like to call it, that helps to transfer data between the two events and then calls a method. The below code does exactly the same:

**In the code behind:**

```
int counter = 0;

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTappedClass SingleTapInstance = new MyTappedClass()
        {
            Handled = e.Handled,
            OriginalSource = e.OriginalSource,
            PointerDeviceType = e.PointerDeviceType
        };
        HandleBothTapEvents(SingleTapInstance);
    }

    private void Button_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTappedClass DoubleTapInstance = new MyTappedClass()
        {
            Handled = e.Handled,
            OriginalSource = e.OriginalSource,
            PointerDeviceType = e.PointerDeviceType
        };
        HandleBothTapEvents(DoubleTapInstance);
    }

    private void HandleBothTapEvents(MyTappedClass TapData)
    {
        if (TapData != null)
        {
            counter++;
            Hello.Content = counter.ToString();
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("No Tap event data transfered");
    }
```

**The supporting class**

and the `BridgeClass` where ever you want to put it. My advice put it in the Helpers Folder (if you have any).

```
public class MyTappedClass
{
    public object OriginalSource { get; set; }

    public PointerDeviceType PointerDeviceType { get; set; }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }

}
```

**Note:** This is just a quick workaround that'll work really well I don't know if there's a conventional way to achieve this but then there is no single correct answer in programming so I guess you can use this. The functionality can be made more versatile by using `Interfaces` to transfer the data between the two events instead of a `BridgeClass` as Interfaces are designed to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `IsDoubleTapEnabled` property should do what you want but many people often miss the fact that this **is automatically set to true if you have an event handler set for the DoubleTap event** on control. Remove the eventhandler if you have one set and you should be able to get all click events in rapid succession.